# Inaccurate real-time audio FFT interpretation with Python

Tags: python, audio, fft, librosa

I'm trying to use Python to create a live music visualization. The libraries I'm using are SoundCard (for live audio capture) and Librosa (for short-time Fourier transform).

However I suspect I'm not interpreting the audio data correctly. Looking at the 100Hz-200Hz bin, I get a constant stream of sound even when the song doesn't contain that much bass (or really, any whatsoever). I admit I am a bit in over my head with all the audio processing FFT stuff, since it's not really my expertise and the math beats me most of the time.

This is the function that captures and analyses the audio. `lb` is set to the speakers and works properly. `Fs` is set to 48000 and I record 1000 frames in the attempt of keeping 48FPS. `fftwindowsize` is set to 2048*8 because... I'm not sure. I increased the number until Librosa stopped throwing warnings.

```
def audioanalysis():
    with lb.recorder(samplerate=Fs) as mic:
        rawdata = mic.record(numframes=1000)
        datalen: int = int(rawdata.size/2)
        monodata = numpy.empty(datalen)
        for x in range(0, datalen):
            monodata[x] = max(rawdata[x][0], rawdata[x][1])
        data = numpy.abs(librosa.stft(monodata, n_fft=fftwindowsize, hop_length=1024))
        return librosa.amplitude_to_db(data, ref=numpy.max)
```

And the code for making buckets:

```
frequencies = librosa.core.fft_frequencies(n_fft=fftwindowsize)
freq_index_ratio = len(frequencies)/frequencies[len(frequencies)-1] / 2

[...]

for i in range(0,buckets):
            avg = 0
            for j in range (i * bucketsize, (i+1)*bucketsize):
                avg += amp(spectrogram=spectrogram, freq=j)
            amps[i] = avg/bucketsize
    
def amp(spectrogram, freq) -> float:
    return spectrogram[int(freq*freq_index_ratio)]
```

Over the course of a song, amps[1] (so 100Hz-200Hz) stays in the -50dB to -30dB range, which isn't really useful or representative of the song playing.

Is my FFT analysis wrong? Is there no way to better interpret short samples of sound?

P.S. I know my Python code isn't excellent. This is my first project in Python :)

Comment: I haven't looked in detail at the code, and I don't know what your source audio is, but there is possibly nothing abnormal about the 100-200Hz range being in the -50 to -30dB range.  Remember that that frequency range is only a small slice of the total sound energy.  Note also that higher frequencies in general will have even less energy, so you may want to assign a higher weight to them in your visualization.  Have you tried looking at your audio source in an existing spectrum analyzer, such as Audizr?

Comment: Also you should not take the max value of the two stereo channels to 'monoize' the signal.  It would be more correct to sum them (or take the average).

Comment: In addition to @CharlesSavoie 's comments, be aware that frequencies may be present depending on phase offset and windowing that you otherwise wouldn't suspect. I would recommend speaking to your institute's physics or acoustics department for a little more flavour as to what is going on here.